# Replace featured image with post meta

Tags: html, wordpress, video

I would like code to allow a post meta condition in WordPress.  For example, if a post has the meta key 'Video', it would replace a featured image with a meta key; otherwise the featured image would show.

featured image code :

```
<?php $image_ratio_case = my_image_ratio_case('1x'); do_action('my_thumbnail', 'my_thumb_16x9_0x', 'class-16x9', 1, NULL, $image_ratio_case);?>
```

meta post code:

```
<video autoplay loop muted width="100%" height="auto" src="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Video', true ) ); ?>"></video>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i want function like if{ else {

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt give any tip about, where the code can be placed and what is your actual Problem i can only give this answer, hope this helps :)

```
if (is_array(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Video', true )) || is_string(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Video', true ))) {
    //echo the video
} else {
    //echo the img
}
```